# Macbook Pro - issue with mailspring

Tags: macbook-pro

I have issue with mailspring - with keyboard shortcut. Many times I'm switching from Macbook and Apple Studio (different resolution)

I need to create shortcut in mailspring to quickly change layout size, there are no shortcuts for that by default in mailspring.

I don't know how to create custom shortcut for that

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by change “the layout size?”  Is that resolution or something else?

Comment: Yes, shure
When I'm going to settings/appearance/layout/scaling
I would like to have keyboard shortcut to scale+/scale-